# v4l2 device left and right video streams of stereo camera using gstreamer

Tags: python, opencv, gstreamer-1.0

I am opening my v4l2 device and both left and right streams are joined and opened at the same time, is there a way to split left and right sensor image frames and display them simultaneously using gstreamer?

EDIT1:

OK, So, I have a v4l2 device and a stereo camera which has both left and right streams writing to /dev/video0 and using gstreamer,I was able to view both the frames, I would like to know how to split left frame and right frame and display in separate windows. Also, I am trying out this script in opencv too, where I am only getting right video stream, I want to be able to view both streams in separate windows either in opencv or using gstreamer.

The below is openCV one

```
import os
import v4l2capture
import select
import numpy as np
import cv2

video = cv2.VideoCapture("/dev/video0")

while(True):
     ret,frame = video.read()

     cv2.imshow('whatever',frame)
     key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF
     if(key == ord("q")):
           break

video.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

The normal gstreamer application is just using a source and sink

```
gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src ! xvimagesink
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the answer to my question here,

https://www.stereolabs.com/docs/opencv/python/